# MediaPlayer + MediaRecorder for rtsp stream?

Tags: media-player, rtsp, mediarecorder, video-recording

Is it possible to use both `MediaPlayer` and `MediaRecorder` simultaneously to function with rtsp stream?

For example,I would use `MediaPlayer` to play live video stream

`MediaPlayer.setDataSource("rtsp://link:port/parameters.sdp?");`

and then set a button to use `MediaRecorder` to record the live stream and save it locally(or remotely if possible)

`MediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/liveRTSP.mp4");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you do not need them to share the same underlying RTP connection you should be fine. Using both of these classes will result in two outstanding RTSP connections to the RTSP server. If it can handle that and you are not required to synchronize both of these connections (one of them may lag behind the other, but the delay would be small and is not guaranteed) then you are fine.

Comment: ,Thank you for your reply,when you say "do not need them to share the same underlying RTP connection",do you mean I cannot use both function on the same `setDataSource`?

Comment: @FayZan it depends on which overload of the `setDataSource` you are using. If the one that takes a string or an uri I believe it will result in both objects having an explicit RTP connection. If you wrap an underlying connection under the `MediaDataSource` interface then you could share one connection.